Rendering UI in React JS
I recently learnt that React renders a snapshot of the UI before the set function is called to change the state and re-rendering is perform. The entire JSX works with the previous state. For example:
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function FeedbackForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  function handleClick() {
    setName(prompt('What is your name?'));
    alert(`Hello, ${name}!`);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      Greet
    </button>
  );
}


After giving a name in the prompt box, the alert still says : Hello, !. It is because the alert takes name from the first rendering which is null.
According to the above description this code:
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Form() {
  const [to, setTo] = useState('Alice');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('Hello');

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      alert(`You said ${message} to ${to}`);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        To:{' '}
        <select
          value={to}
          onChange={e => setTo(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="Alice">Alice</option>
          <option value="Bob">Bob</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <textarea
        placeholder="Message"
        value={message}
        onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  );
}

So as onchange event fires, the state of both the variable to and message changes, and when the form is submitted, the alert should show : You said Hello to Alice rather it shows alert which includes new to and new message.
Where I am getting wrong?

Your question isn't quite clear, it makes sense right that the new value is shown? Please include a [mre] and clarify the actual issue

Your understanding of the React rendering lifecycle and state management isn't quite right. The onchange event fires whenever the input changes. When that event is triggered, it asynchronously queues the state to update via setTo and setMessage. So long as nothing is blocking the event loop, it will update the state and re-render (if there is anything to re-render). The state is actually updated in a following event loop cycle, but this will execute in the background before you've had a chance to notice it. It does not technically update within your onchange routine. In your second example, there isn't anything to actually re-render so you aren't seeing changes in the UI. However, the state IS updating.
The reason you're seeing Hello, ! in the first example is because the handleClick method blocks the event loop until it completes, which means the state of name won't actually update until a following event loop cycle.
In short, the event loop is executing multiple cycles while you're manipulating the UI input fields, giving React time to update the state variables. By the time you trigger an event for submitting the form, you can be assured that any prior changes to the state have completed.
If you want to see this in a bit of a delayed fashion, you could simply change your onchange event handler to the following:
{e => {console.log(to); console.log(message); setMessage(e.target.value)}}

In the above case, you'll see the previous state of the to and message variables before they've been updated. If you make several changes to trigger multiple console logs, then you'll see that the state is indeed updated before the form is submitted.
You "queue" changes to state by enqueuing a new event to the event loop. JavaScript is single threaded, so the event loop dequeues whatever event is next in line. But if you're just clicking on elements in the DOM, the event loop is assuredly executing events in the background, because it would be wildly inefficient to block until you've clicked a particular button to process all the state changes.
Here is a full example that will show you how the state is truly updating on each onchange event.
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Form() {
  const [to, setTo] = useState('Alice');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('Hello');

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      alert(`You said ${message} to ${to}`);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        To:{' '}
        <select
          value={to}
          onChange={e => setTo(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="Alice">Alice</option>
          <option value="Bob">Bob</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <textarea
        placeholder="Message"
        value={message}
        onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      />
      <h1>To: {to}</h1>
      <p>Message: {message}</p>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  );


The addition of the h1 and p are not necessary since the form inputs literally are using the current state values of the to and message variables, but putting those state values outside of the input may help you see what is happening.

I wanted to now how the second code doesn't return : You said Hello to Alice.

Because by the time the form is submitted, the state changes have processed. This is because the onchange event updates the state asynchronously and those asynchronous events will complete before the form submit event is executed.

Still not able to get the first part. Can you elaborate? not aware of the event loop.

The event loop is the crux of your confusion. I added a bit more context for you. I hope it helps.

Can we say that- when an onChange is fired the component re-renders. But this re-renders doesn't call the function handleSubmit, and hence no alert is seen. In this case when onChange is fired two times, the component renders twice, each time changing the value of to and message, in a sequence which onChange gets fired first. Now, when the onSubmit fires, a third time re-rendering takes place with new to and message state and handleSubmit is called with those two new values. Is this the correct way?

The onChange event is not directly updating the state. It's calling a setState method that will asynchronously update the state, and when a React component's state updates the component will re-render (if there is anything to re-render). Yes, re-rendering will not cause the alert to execute. The only thing calling alert is your handleSubmit routine, which only happens when you click your submit button. By the time you've clicked that button, React will have processed any asynchronous state changes that were triggered.

Yeah i mean the onChange calling the setState to change the state and re-rendering.

But is this true that the component gets rendered thrice before the alert?

Technically onChange IS triggering a re-render, because notice that the value property of your inputs is the value of your state variables. If you didn't update the state in onChange, you would notice that no matter what you do to the inputs their values remain the same. This would be annoying behavior for a user, but it would be good for you to try for observation.

Yes it's true that the component is being re-rendered each time you change your inputs. That is because you're updating the state of the component and the component renders those state variables as values for your inputs. State updates don't necessarily mean re-rendering. For optimization purposes, React only re-renders when the next rendering state would be different than the prior. But in your case any change to the state variables will trigger a re-render.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

When your React function is called, the DOM is generated based on its current state. If somewhere in the code, a hook is activated or event is created that would change the DOM, a re-render will happen. So any time you see "setX()" in code, that bit of code will not "run" on the current render, but some time after this render, and before the next* render. This is why infinite renders happen if you call a hook each render.
EDIT: *"next" render meaning some later render. Technically if you see a render and then a hook is called, there could potentially be a render between "this" current render and the "next" render.

In React.js, setName() and other state changes are not executed directly, but asynchronously. This results in the old name being output in your code. A simple solution would be:
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function FeedbackForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  function handleClick() {
    const newName = prompt('What is your name?');
    setName(newName);
    alert(`Hello, ${newName}!`);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      Greet
    </button>
  );
}


Sorry I didn't ask this. I wanted to now how the second code doesn't return : You said Hello to Alice.
